# Netty HttpProxyHandler example

Tags: netty

I am studying Netty. I'd like to implement a proxy that traces some http access for the company, as part of the data leak prevention program.

Netty seems to be a good candidate for this.

I am trying to build an http proxy, having the ability to modify requests and responses in some specific cases.

I had a look at little poxy but find the documentation not rich enough to feel comfortable at implementing a solution with it.

So I am focusing on Netty.

I have found a reference to a class named HttpProxyHandler but cannot find any example, or any documentation describing what this class and how it should be used.

Am I going to the right direction?

Thanks and regards

Gilles

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [HttpProxyHandler](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/proxy/HttpProxyHandler.html#handleResponse(io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext,%20java.lang.Object)) is meant for connecting to an external proxy, not for implementing your own.

If you want to learn more about Netty then I suggest looking at [HexDumpProxy](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/proxy/HexDumpProxy.java) example

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I understand how this DumpProxy works. What I don't understand, is how to use it from a "client/browser" perspective. I see the proxy getting connected to google and returning the google access. Do you know a good example where the client get connected and its call is redirected to the target site? That is the part I am missing at the moment.

Comment: I have described my use case here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40523234/netty-http-interception-proxy